# Pop up an error message when I try to add the credit memo in SAP B1

Tags: sapb1

I issued the delivery order and AR Invoice on 31/05/2018. The goods arrived in Jun then, I want to issue a tax only AR Credit Memo to **remove the GST**.

I received  an error message: When I try to add the credit memo.

> [A/R Credit Memo - Rows - Tax Only][line: 1] , 'Cannot disable the tax-only calculation in a A/R Credit Memos document that was based on another document' [Message 0-0]

what is the cause of this? and how can I resolve it

Please advise how I can remove the GST. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible to create a tax only credit memo based on an invoice.

If the customer was issued with an invoice including tax, for traceability, your best option is to credit the entire invoice & then re-issue it without tax.

Are you getting the goods back? If so, you can use a stand alone tax only credit memo & then automatically receive them back into stock. Please note that the items will be received at the current item cost, you may have to make manual adjustments.

If you're not getting the goods back, technically the easiest way is to create a manual JE (de-select Automatic tax) within the adjustments in the internal reconciliation with the tax account as GL account & reconcile that with the open invoice. The balance due of the invoice is then reduced by that amount. You need to check with your tax accountant, though, it may not be permissible in your country.

Also, What this handling error message means is that the Tax-Only tickbox cannot be used as it was not used in the base document. The tax selection for deliveries, AR Invoices (or any document that creates a journal entry) must be consistent.

For example:

It is similar to creating a delivery with tax code A, then copying

the delivery to an invoice and trying to change the tax code to

code B, this is not possible.

It is not possible to create a target docuemnt without the tax-only tick box if the base document has it and vice versa.

From SCN!